# I want to know the executeUpdate () returns a value should be how to write

Tags: java

```
public void insert(Integer id, String name, String orign, String specification, String unit, String amount, String price) {
    Connection conn = s.getConnection();
    String sql = "insert cargo_list values(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, id);
    ps.setString(2, name);
    ps.setString(3, orign);
    ps.setString(4, specification);
    ps.setString(5, unit);
    ps.setString(6, amount);
    ps.setString(7, price);
    a = ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

I want to know the `executeUpdate()` returns a value should be how to write
(//int a is wrong //)
please help me to correct this mistake. thanks

Comment: please provide the code or an example so we can help as your question is not detailed enough

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()), `executeUpdate()` returns number of records updated for an update (or DML) statement. If you want to log the warning then you can check the reurn value and log it (i.e. `log(a  +  " records updated")`).